# remove values less than a number in excel array

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a value that needs to calculate stock based on the previous years sales:

```
{=CEILING(SUM(IF('Inventory Transactions'!$H$2:$H$7137=LEFT($B6,3),IF('Inventory Transactions'!$O$2:$O$7137='Do Not Edit This Sheet'!C6,'Inventory Transactions'!$AD$2:$AD$7137,0),0))/12*2,25)}
```

In the cell I was testing this in that returns 50 (when I do the math manually this makes sense) calculating sales where the type of sale from do not edit this sheet is correct then dividing by 12 and multiplying by 2 to get a 2 month supply and rounding up to the next highest multiple of 25 units. however my boss now wants to make anything that sold less than 100 units last year or 17/month "0" and I have tried

```
{=CEILING(IF(SUM(IF('Inventory Transactions'!$H$2:$H$7137=LEFT($B6,3),IF('Inventory Transactions'!$O$2:$O$7137='Do Not Edit This Sheet'!C6,'Inventory Transactions'!$AD$2:$AD$7137,0),0))/12*2 <=17,0),25)}
```

and

```
{=CEILING(SUM(IF(IF('Inventory Transactions'!$H$2:$H$7137=LEFT($B6,3),IF('Inventory Transactions'!$O$2:$O$7137='Do Not Edit This Sheet'!C6,'Inventory Transactions'!$AD$2:$AD$7137,0),0))< 100,0)/12*2,25)}
```

with no luck it returns 0 either way and shouldn't because it returns 50 regularly which means the number/month is greater than 25

I'm sure its probably a relatively simple problem and I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to analyze your first attempt at changing your formula. The three first functions

> ceiling(IF(SUM(RestOfTheFormula)/12*2 <=17,0),25)

seem to read in plain English: If the sum of RestOfTheFormula is inferior or equal to 17 then  return a zero value or else return nothing (as the FALSE part of the conditionnal statement is not given) , then the result  will be rounded to 25 if superior to zero.

I'm not sure a 100%, but try to make you first IF statement return the value evalued; sthg like:

> ceiling(IF(SUM(RestOfTheFormula)/12*2 <=17,0,SUM(RestOfTheFormula)),25)

or in your terms:

> '=CEILING(IF(SUM(IF('Inventory Transactions'!$H$2:$H$7137=LEFT($B6,3),IF('Inventory Transactions'!$O$2:$O$7137='Do Not Edit This Sheet'!C6,'Inventory Transactions'!$AD$2:$AD$7137,0),0))/12*2 <=17,0,(IF('Inventory Transactions'!$H$2:$H$7137=LEFT($B6,3),IF('Inventory Transactions'!$O$2:$O$7137='Do Not Edit This Sheet'!C6,'Inventory Transactions'!$AD$2:$AD$7137,0),0))),25)

If I'm wrong, let me know i'll just delete this post.